# Using TwitterBootstrapMVC Radio Buttons Without Binding to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

I'm trying to create a form with TwitterBootstrapMVC with the following scenario:

Bind most of the form fields to the backing entity, while using Radio Buttons (that have no backing fields in the entity model) to hide or show specific fields.

So for example:

Allow users to select a specific site from a dropdown list, or let the user choose from a dropdown list of categories and have the app randomly choose a site in that category (after submitting the form, the backing code will look at all of the sites in the category and choose one for the user).

I can bind to the list of websites or categories in the database no problem, but I can't for the life of me create 2 radio buttons that will allow the user to show either the site list or the category list.

Here's a snippet in normal HTML5:

```
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Post to...</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="siteOptions" value="singleSite" checked>
                                Specific Site
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="siteOptions" value="randomSite">
                                Random Site in Category
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And then depending on which of the two radio buttons is chosen, show either the site dropdown list or the category dropdown list.

I've tried this:

```
@using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().LabelWidthMd(2)))
{
        @f.FormGroup().RadioButton("siteOptions", "specificSite")
        @f.FormGroup().RadioButton("siteOptions", "randomSite")
}
```

And it doesn't work, it just puts 2 radio buttons that aren't linked together.  And I've tried changing the 2nd parameter to have the same name, no-go.  From what I've tried so far, the .RadioButtonList() option doesn't work either because I need to pass an IEnumerable<> to it.

So the short of it is:  how can I tie 2+ radio buttons to the same name in TwitterBootstrapMVC without having to bind to the model (for that specific form field), because the model doesn't contain a backing field for this particular value?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured out the answer - so simple:

Just used a hybrid of normal HTML5 in combination around the TwitterBootstrapMVC code, no need to force it to create these extra form elements.